# Track Microsoft Teams userid for who opened the tab (created by bot)

Tags: rest, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft teams bot that creates tab in channel on certain requests.

I want to track who is the user in channel who opens the tab.

Is there a way to do so?

Any help is appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Hey testing for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [Get Context for your Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context#getting-context-by-inserting-url-placeholder-values). It return the User Object ID, Login Hint, User Principle Name of the user who is accessing the Tab

Here is the Method which you can call:
You can also retrieve the information listed above using the Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK by calling

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context) { /* ... */ }).
```

Comment: can you suggest a way to authenticate the context payload recieved if its actually from microsoft teams?